# Rate of convergence (Probabilty)

Tags: probability

I didn't take any probability classes and just remember a bit about what i did in Highschool.
This might be a very elementary question but i'm really curious about it.

Anyway here goes my question:

denote by $N(i)$ the number of times that the experiment turnt up the $i$'th possibility.
denote by $N$ the total number of expremients (or trials).
denote by $P(i)$ the probability of the $i$'th possibility. 
Then we have : $\frac{N(i) }{N }=P(i)$ as $N \to \infty$.

Now i would like to find a  simple example of an experiment so that  we can determine a $m$ and an $\epsilon$ for wich we have :

$$
\forall N\geq m \qquad \left|\frac{N(i) }{N }-P(i)\right|<\epsilon
$$

If the question is not clear i will try to restate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is *possible* that if you toss a fair coin a very large number  of times, you will get all heads. So the assertion needs to be modified. For details, please see Wikipedia, *Law of Large Numbers.*

Comment: The usual notion of a limit is actually not applicable to convergence when it comes to probability. Check out the following for what we mean when finite experiments "converge" probabilistically. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables

Comment: i knew that my thoughts where too simple...thanks for the suggestions!